# how to disable editing for only some rows in ag grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

i want to enable only some rows in my ag-grid(exemple :2/5) based on a condition .

editable:false can't help because it is applied on the whole list unless if there is a method I do not know

any help please

Answer (score 19):

You can just bind `function` to `editable` property in `columnDef`, which will be executed on each try of `edit`

```
editable: this.checkEditFunction.bind(this)
...
checkEditFunction(params){
    //params.node - for row identity
    //params.column - for column identity
    return !params.node.isRowPinned() // - just as sample
}
```

`.bind(this)` - just for accessibility of external functions

Answer (score 5):

You can call `stopEditing()` method of `gridApi` after checking the condition - keeping `editable: true`.

Suppose, you are editing the row,

```
(rowEditingStarted)="onRowEditingStarted($event)"
```

Then in your component, you can stop the editing based on a check as per below.

```
private onRowEditingStarted($event) {
  if(!$event.data.propertyToCheck == <someCondition>) {
    this.gridApi.stopEditing();
}
```

---

Update:

You'll have to update template for the editing event.

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid
  ....
 (rowEditingStarted)="onRowEditingStarted($event)"
  ....
 ></ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

Check this example for reference: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-cell-editing

Comment: can you please tell me if we should declare it this way 
            model.columns = [
                {checkboxSelection: enableEdition,
     editable: true
                    rowEditingStarted:onRowEditingStarted($event)
                }]

Comment: var onRowEditingStarted=function($event) {
                  if($event.data.x === model.x) {
                    this.gridApi.stopEditing();
                }
            };

Comment: I don't think i can do that beacuse i'm in angularJS 1.5

Comment: Note: I needed to use `cellEditingStarted` instead of `rowEditingStarted` since I was not using _Full Row Editing_